# Can use of "usermod -G" break xserver access permission?

Tags: permissions, xorg

Ubuntu Xfce 16.04

I've made the noob error of loosing my groups with a

```
usermod -G video df4ze
```

but immediately re-add my user to each loosed groups.

Everythings seems to work (sudo, etc...) but I was warned by a "Wrong password" when Ubuntu ask me to install new update. Not really a problem because I could update in cli mode.

Forgot aubout it, I shut it down ... and now getting stuck in recovery mode and can't launch anymore xserver :

```
unable to connect to xserver : connection refused
```

Using `sudo startx` it launch but got too much troubles...

- I've check 4 times the removed groups with a `sudo grep group /var/log/auth.log`.
- In `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.conf` set `allowed_users` to `anybody`
- Change owner of `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` for my user:group
- Relaunch xserver legacy with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04`
- Seeing that error message talk about `tty`, I've add my user to `tty` group. Now I do not have the `tty` error message but still the "connection refused"
- Then I ran several commands lines but still got the same issue:

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -f
  sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
  ```

Last chance will be a `rm -R /` but i'm sure there is a better way!

Comment: No it should not AFAIK - although running `sudo startx` almost certainly **will**. What exactly are your groups *now* (i.e. the output of command `id`)?

Comment: Sorry for the late, Too impatient, i've taken the last solution ;) it's a fresh PC and just the 5st time I erased it...! Thanks anyway